# rails update the parameters from one controller to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a 3 tables called cinemas, users, user_views, cinema_ratings, profile

So my user_views table is  having :user_id and cinema_id

And what I wanted to do is
In my cinema_ratings controller I wanted to update, create and delete my user_views tables.

And I wanted to write like

```
 if current_user has not done cinema_ratings ?
  if current_user_id is present in user_views[user_id]?
   #do some thing
  else
     update user_id in user_views 
  else
    delete user_id and cinema_id in user views
    redirect to actual cinemas page
#do some thing
```

end
end

This what I wanted to do but I dont know how to call user_views table to update, read and delete from this controller.

So can any one tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the table updates in the `User` model.

```
def view! (cinema)
  self.user_views.create!(cinema_id: cinema.id)
end
```

Then in your controller, wherever you need to call it, you just call `@user.view!(@cinema)`

Typically any time you're dealing with the database, you want to keep that logic in the model. There's a bit of a standard for '[fat models, lean controllers](https://www.google.com/search?q=fat%20model%20skinny%20controller&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS571US571&oq=fat%20model)'.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

So... your syntax is way off for those if statements... but I'll try.

You can put those checks in the model as well. I usually do. So:

```
def viewed? (cinema)
  !self.user_views.where(id: cinema.id).empty?
end
```

you can then check to see if a user has viewed movies at a certain cinema with `@user.viewed?(@cinema)`. That would be part of your conditional.

The idea of all this, and of your question:

> This what I wanted to do but I dont know how to call user_views table to update, read and delete from this controller.

Put methods on your models, and call them from the controller.

Comment: I could able understand the idea can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: that is the detail... hmmm. updating my answer a bit.